# Django reverse and redirect after ajax request returns django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-urls

I call a specific `url` from and `ajax` function which will calls the respective view function. In view function I want to redirect the page by calling another view (because I can't render after ajax request).

Here are my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^search_result/.+$', views.search_result, name='search_result'),
    url(r'^new_search_result/$',
        views.new_search_result,
        kwargs={'selected': '', 'keyword': ''},
        name='new_search_result')
]
```

And here is the `search_result` view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def search_result(request):
    keyword = request.POST.get('keyword')
    selected = request.POST.get('selected')
    url = reverse('new_search_result',
                  kwargs={'keyword': keyword,
                          'selected': selected})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    # return render(request, 'SearchEngine/search_result.html', {'all_results': result})
```

And here is the `new_search_result` view:

```
def new_search_result(request, selected={}, keyword=''):
   # code blocks
```

But in consul I get this error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'new_search_result' with keyword arguments '{'selected': '{"PANTHER":"ftp.pantherdb.org","Pasteur Insitute":"ftp.pasteur.fr","Rat Genome Database":"ftp.rgd.mcw.edu"}', 'keyword': 'dfasdf'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['searchengine/new_search_result/$']
[22/Jul/2017 12:52:12] "POST /searchengine/search_result/dfasdf HTTP/1.1" 500 16814
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The `kwargs` argument to `url`**

The extra `kwargs` argument you provide to the call to `url` allows you to define extra parameters that are then passed on to the view. They do not define extra arguments that are provided when fetching the url - the call to `reverse` does not know about these extra arguments, the call to `reverse` only knows about the arguments defined in the url pattern.

So if you have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', myview,
        kwargs={'foo': 'bar'}),
]
```

This means that when your url is fetched as `blog/1111` then view `myview` is invoked with two parameters: `year` with value `1111` and `foo` with value `bar`.

Only the view sees the extra argument `foo` - it is not in the url, and it is not provided to the `reverse` function. The `kwargs` argument of the `reverse` function actually refers to the arguments defined in the url pattern.

**Passing parameters to a view**

So looking at what you're trying to achieve: you want to redirect the user's browser to a different URL, such that the resulting view will have access to the `keyword` and `selected` parameters.

If you wanted that data to be hidden from the user, you would have to store it in the session. Assuming this is not the case you have three ways to pass parameters to a view: via GET parameters, via POST data and view the url. In your case as you're redirecting to another page, you can't use a POST request. You could use the url but for a search page I would think the best option would be to use GET parameters.

So in your `search_result` view you could add a query string to the URL ie. `?keyword=...&selected=...`. For example:

```
import urllib
@csrf_exempt
def search_result(request):
    args = {
        'keyword': request.POST.get('keyword'),
        'selected': request.POST.get('selected')
    }
    url = '%s?%s' % (
        reverse('new_search_result'),
        urllib.urlencode(args)
    )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

And your `new_search_result` view would read those from the request:

```
def new_search_result(request):
    selected = request.GET.get('selected')
    keyword = request.GET.get('keyword')
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification, so what should I do in this case to pass those variables to another view?

Comment: @Mat I've updated the answer to include one way you could achieve what you are trying to do. There are probably other ways, and the best would depend on the details of what you're doing, but hopefully this is enough to show you how this is generally achieved.